# Как убрать лого "welcome to raspberry pi desktop"?

Tags: raspberry-pi

После июньского обновления системы, во врем загрузки устройства стало появляться следующее сообщение:[image: сообщение]
Как от него избавиться? Прописывать logo.nologo в cmdline.txt пробовал.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Установите Raspbian Jessie **Lite** :)

Comment: Решение, конечно, интересное. Но, так как я не являюсь гуру в плане Линуксов, не могу быть уверен, что "лайтовая" версия подойдет мне в дальнейшем изучении RPi.

Comment: это было своего рода шуткой. Лайтовая версия не содержит GUI вообще, как и заставки при запуске - вот вам и решение как _от него избавиться_.

Comment: Ха! Что ж, шутка засчитана. Жаль, правда, 3.5-минутное гугление не показало, что там GUI отсутствует, иначе я бы шутку понял. Видимо, как всегда написали самое важное в самом конце.

Comment: [хм...](https://www.screencast.com/t/RSGAle7t)

Comment: всё верно, в конце написали)

Comment: не отвечаю за работоспособность, но можете попробовать [этот вариант](https://yingtongli.me/blog/2016/12/21/splash.html)

Comment: К сожалению, этот вариант я уже пробовал. Максимум что он убирает это "колор тест" и изображение 4 малинок в начале загрузки. Но суть вопроса вы уловили, да, мне нужно свое изображение во время загрузки RPi.

Comment: если не секрет, зачем?)

Comment: Эстетически мешает наверное. Ну представьте, на экране загрузке моя красивая картиночка (а может даже анимация, и такие примеры находил). И тут в последний момент: "велком то зе Распберри Пай Десктоп". Как то не очень. А вообще этот RPi будет вмонтирован в приборную панель одного устройства, и в автозапуске у него находятся полноэкранные приложения необходимые для работы этого устройства. И чтобы не усложнять жизнь конечного пользователя, хотелось бы избавиться от всех ненужных записей/картиночек/сообщений и тому подобное.

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант отключить plymouth или перейти по /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ и поставить свою картинку на заставку.

Answer (score 0):

для решения этой проблемы мне помогло:

в boot/config.txt

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

поменять на

```
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

когда запускаете без hdmi, убрать "#"